# Absolutely positioned element overlapping the right side of the screen with no scrolling

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am attempting to absolutely position a `div` of unknown height and width so that it sits partially off of the right side of my screen, while disabling scrolling to the right. It's working just fine when I attempt to do this on the *left* side of the screen. But when I try it on the right side of my screen, I'm getting problems.

I've attempted to use `overflow-x` to solve this problem, but that makes the entire `div` disappear unexpectedly.

```css
.parent1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.child1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  left: -50px;
  top: 0;
}

.parent2 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.child2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  right: -50px;
  top: 0;
}

.parent3 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.child3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  right: -50px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="child1">
    This works on the left: half of the DIV is off the screen and un-scrollable; the other half is showing.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child2">
    But when I try it on the right, I'm able to scroll the screen right and see this whole DIV.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent3">
  <div class="child3">
    I would expect overflow-x to solve this problem, but it hides the DIV entirely.
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h1c0ewgt/)

How can I make it so that my `div` is positioned off of the right side of the screen, while scrolling is disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to apply `overflow-x: hidden` on the `body` instead. Your solution to hide the `overflow-x` for the `parent` would work if the parent itself was scrollable otherwise there is nothing to hide.

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.parent1 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.child1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  left: -50px;
  top: 0;
}

.parent2 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.child2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  right: -50px;
  top: 0;
}

.parent3 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.child3 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  right: -50px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="child1">
    This works on the left: half of the DIV is off the screen and un-scrollable; the other half is showing.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
  <div class="child2">
    But when I try it on the right, I'm able to scroll the screen right and see this whole DIV.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="parent3">
  <div class="child3">
    I would expect overflow-x to solve this problem, but it hides the DIV entirely.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad I helped. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Change the styling of child 2 to be `position: fixed`

```
.child2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  right: -50px;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: This fixes the DIV to a specific spot on the page as I scroll; I don't want to do that.